# Strange behavior Java += operator

Tags: java, operator-keyword

Can anyone explain this to me ,

```
String str = "Hello";

str += ((char)97) +2; // str = "Hello99";

str = str +((char)97)+2; // str = "Helloa2";
```

does the `+=` operator evaluate the right side first then it concatenate it with the left side ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference has to do with the order of operations. The following:

```
str += ((char)97) +2;
```

is equivalent to:

```
str = str + (((char)97) + 2);
```

On the other hand, the following:

```
str = str +((char)97)+2;
```

is equivalent to:

```
str = (str + ((char)97)) + 2;
```

Note the difference in the placement of parentheses.

Now let's consider the two cases:

1) `str = str + (((char)97) + 2)`:

Here, `97 + 2` is evaluated first. The result is an `int` (`99`), which is converted to string and appended to `str`. The result is `"Hello99"`.

2) `str = (str + ((char)97)) + 2`:

Here, `(char)97` (`'a'`) is appended to the string, and then `2` is converted to string and appended to the result. This gives `"Helloa2"`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The relevant section of the JLS is here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/first_edition/html/15.doc.html#5304

> At run time, the expression is evaluated in one of two ways. If the
>   left-hand operand expression is not an array access expression, then
>   four steps are required:
>
> - First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to
>     produce a variable. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the
>     assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason; the
>     right-hand operand is not evaluated and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the value of the left-hand operand is saved and then **the
>     right-hand operand is evaluated**. If this evaluation completes
>     abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the
>     same reason and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, **the saved value of
>     the left-hand variable and the value of the right-hand operand are
>     used to perform the binary operation indicated by the compound
>     assignment operator**. If this operation completes abruptly (the only
>     possibility is an integer division by zero-see §15.16.2), then the
>     assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason and no
>     assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the result of the binary operation is
>     converted to the type of the left-hand variable and the result of the
>     conversion is stored into the variable.

(Emphasis by me.)

Answer (score 2):

This is all about operator associativity.

```
str += ((char)97) +2;
```

Would translate to:

```
str = str + ( ((char)97)+2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first line is equivalent to:

```
str = str + ((char)97) + 2);
```

while your second one is equivalent to:

```
str = (str + ((char)97)) + 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 str = str +((char)97)+2
```

because first is string  '+' operator is used as string concat (other values are converted to string)

```
str +=((char)97)+2
```

first right side is evaluated to 99 ( two byte sum ) than is  str + 99 -> string concat